Invoice OCR insertion to SQL Workbench
Invoice OCR runs successfully when extracted in excel however does not provided appropriate result when I want it in database while using SQL workbench.
I need for every track id, it should populate following fields
enter image description here - Output for every track id
I tried Python pdfplumber to extract data from invoices and wanted to extract the data. I performed the operation and achieved success when extracted in excel
However, the same is not running successful when i want the same information in database. Also, in database, I do not want duplicate records.
Definition for duplicate record will be combination of Track id, line item and Line total. A composite key can be created in this case to identify duplicate
import pdfplumber
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import mysql.connector

# Folder containing PDF invoices
folder_path = "C:/Rakesh/SQL Workbench/Invoices"

# Get a list of all PDF files in the folder
pdf_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.lower().endswith('.pdf')]

# Define the regular expression pattern to capture "Eversource" or the word after "Remit Payment To:"
vendor_name_pattern = r"Remit Payment To:\s*(\b\w+\b)"

# Define patterns for various fields
value_pattern = re.compile(r'(-?\$[\d,]+\.\d+)')
total_usage_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+\.\d+)\s*(kWh)')
total_demand_pattern = re.compile(r'Total Demand Use\s*(-?\d+\.\d+)\s*(kW)')
service_address_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,5} [A-Za-z ]+)\s+([A-Z\s]+)\s+([A-Z]{2})\s+(\d{5}(-\d{4})?)')

# List of balance-related keywords
balance_keywords = ["Balance Brought Forward", "Balance Forward", "BBF", "Previous Balance", "Past Due"]

# List of Late Payment-related keywords
late_payment_keywords = ["Late Payment", "Interest Charge", "Finance Charge"]

# Fixed line items to check
fixed_line_items = ["Total Demand", "Total Cost", "Total Tax", "Total Usage", "BBF", "Late Fees", "Gross Total"]

# Columns to be blanked out if values are not found
columns_to_blank = ['MeterRead', 'Units', 'UnitType', 'ConvFactor', 'LossFactor2', 'CPU', 'LineTotal', 'LineTax']

# Connect to MySQL
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="Oneday@11",
    database="Invoice_OCR"
)
cursor = conn.cursor()

for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    pdf_path = os.path.join(folder_path, pdf_file)

    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
        # Initialize a list to store extracted data for each PDF file
        extracted_data = []

        for line_item in fixed_line_items:
            data_dict = {  # Start with a dictionary with all fields set to None
                'TrackID': None,
                'InvoiceNumber': None,
                'Customer': None,
                'VendorName': None,
                'VendorCode': None,
                'VendorAccount': None,
                'BillDate': None,
                'DueDate': None,
                'ReadDate': None,
                'PrevDate': None,
                'LocationCode': None,
                'LocationName': None,
                'UtilityType': None,
                'LineText': line_item,  # LineText is fixed to the current line item
                'MeterRead': None,
                'Units': None,
                'UnitType': None,
                'ConvFactor': None,
                'LossFactor2': None,
                'CPU': None,
                'LineTotal': None,
                'LineTax': None,
                'Currency': None,
                'TariffCode': None,
                'UtilClass': None,
                'TimeClass': None,
                'ReadingClass': None,
                'MeterNumber': None,
                'AmendedInvoiceRef': None,
                'ServiceAddress': None,
                'City': None,
                'State': None,
                'ZipCode': None,
            }

            # Iterate through each page in the PDF
            for page in pdf.pages:
                page_text = page.extract_text()
                if page_text:
                    # Split the text into lines
                    lines = page_text.split('\n')

                    # Search for the vendor name pattern
                    vendor_name_match = re.search(vendor_name_pattern, page_text)
                    if vendor_name_match:
                        data_dict['VendorName'] = vendor_name_match.group(1)

                    # Search for the service address pattern
                    service_address_match = service_address_pattern.search(page_text)
                    if service_address_match:
                        data_dict['ServiceAddress'] = service_address_match.group(1)
                        data_dict['City'] = service_address_match.group(2).strip()
                        data_dict['State'] = service_address_match.group(3)
                        data_dict['ZipCode'] = service_address_match.group(4)

                    # Iterate through the lines to find relevant information
                    for line_index, line in enumerate(lines):
                        if "#" in line:
                            match = re.search(r'(\S{8}) #', line)
                            if match:
                                data_dict['TrackID'] = match.group(1)

                        elif "Account Number" in line:
                            vendor_account = line.split(":")[1].replace(" ", "").strip()
                            data_dict['VendorAccount'] = vendor_account
                            if vendor_account and data_dict['BillDate']:
                                invoice_date = pd.to_datetime(data_dict['BillDate']).strftime('%Y%m%d')
                                invoice_number = f"{vendor_account}{invoice_date}"
                                data_dict['InvoiceNumber'] = invoice_number

                        elif "Service Provided To:" in line and line_index + 1 < len(lines):
                            next_line_index = line_index + 1
                            if next_line_index < len(lines):
                                customer_match = re.search(r'\b([A-Z ]+)\b', lines[next_line_index])
                                if customer_match:
                                    data_dict['Customer'] = customer_match.group(1)

                        elif "Statement Date" in line:
                            data_dict['BillDate'] = line.split(":")[1].strip()

                        elif "Due Date" in line:
                            data_dict['DueDate'] = line.split(" ")[1].strip()

                        # Extract 'PrevDate' and 'ReadDate' from the "Service from" line
                        date_matches = re.findall(r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})', line)
                        if "Service from" in line and len(date_matches) >= 2:
                            data_dict['PrevDate'] = date_matches[0]
                            data_dict['ReadDate'] = date_matches[1]

                        elif "Location" in line:
                            if "Code" in line:
                                data_dict['LocationCode'] = line.split(":")[1].strip()
                            elif "Name" in line:
                                data_dict['LocationName'] = line.split(":")[1].strip()

                        elif f"Total {line_item}" in line:
                            extracted_info = value_pattern.findall(line)
                            if extracted_info:
                                for info in extracted_info:
                                    try:
                                        info = info.replace(",", "").replace("$", "").strip()  # Clean the value
                                        value = float(info) if "-" not in info else -float(info)
                                        data_dict['LineTotal'] = value
                                    except ValueError:
                                        print(f"Could not convert LineTotal value: {info}")
                                        data_dict['LineTotal'] = None  # Handle the conversion error

                                    # Set additional fields if applicable
                                    if line_item == "Total Usage":
                                        data_dict['Units'], data_dict['UnitType'] = value, "kWh"
                                    elif line_item == "Total Demand":
                                        data_dict['Units'], data_dict['UnitType'] = value, "kW"

            # If no value was found, blank out specific columns
            if data_dict['LineTotal'] is None:
                for column in columns_to_blank:
                    data_dict[column] = ''

            # Ensure the Units and MeterRead data is correctly formatted
            for key in ['Units', 'MeterRead', 'ConvFactor', 'LossFactor2', 'CPU']:
                try:
                    if data_dict[key]:
                        # Remove any non-numeric characters if 'Units', 'MeterRead', etc. are expected to be numeric
                        data_dict[key] = re.sub(r'[^\d.-]', '', data_dict[key])
                        data_dict[key] = float(data_dict[key])  # Convert to float
                    else:
                        data_dict[key] = None  # Set to None if value is empty
                except ValueError:
                    data_dict[key] = None  # In case conversion fails, set to None

            # Convert the dates from MM/DD/YY to YYYY-MM-DD before inserting
            for key, value in data_dict.items():
                if 'Date' in key and value:  # If the key contains 'Date' and value is not None
                    data_dict[key] = datetime.strptime(value, "%m/%d/%y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

            # Prepare SQL Insert query with the dictionary values
            columns = ', '.join(data_dict.keys())
            placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(data_dict))
            insert_query = f"INSERT INTO invoices ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders})"

            # Execute the query
            try:
                cursor.execute(insert_query, list(data_dict.values()))
                conn.commit()
            except mysql.connector.IntegrityError:
                print(f"Duplicate entry detected for TrackID: {data_dict['TrackID']}")
            except mysql.connector.DatabaseError as e:
                print(f"DatabaseError: {e}")

# Close the database connection
conn.close()

